# Convert comma separated rows into a table without using CTE or split_string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've hit an interesting problem in our system. A design decision was made to include IDs in a comma separated string which are referenced in the day-to-day functioning of the system. It wasn't causing any problems initially but, now we have a large amount of data, the query to extract information is taking 30-60 seconds. This is mainly down to it checking every row's string for a particular ID and using a function to split each string. I expect that extrapolating this information into an indexed view would speed things up significantly but, although I'm able to create the query to do the work, I can't put it into an indexed view because it uses a cross apply.

The data is currently in this form

| ProductId | OtherProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123, 234, 456 |
| 456 | 987, 987, 876, 512 |

and I need to get it into an indexed view like this

| ProductId | OtherProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 |
| 123 | 234 |
| 123 | 456 |
| 456 | 987 |
| 456 | 876 |
| 456 | 512 |

I can then join by OtherProductId and get the ProductIds associated.

The following will provide the data in a form I can use but takes 30+ seconds to run

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(10)'))) AS OtherProductId
FROM (
        SELECT ProductId,
             CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>'
             + REPLACE(OtherProductIds, ',', '</RowData><RowData>')
             + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
        FROM MySourceTable
     ) t
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
```

I'd like to convert this into an indexed view so I can join it to my actual query and speed things up.

We're using SQL Server 2008 compatibility mode so are unable to make use of split_string and all the other newer features. Changing the code would require too much upheaval and have far-reaching issues in implementing but I am able to change and update the database as necessary.

Comment: It's long past time you fixed the bad decisions (denormalized IDs of all things, using obsolete database versions) instead of trying to cover up the consequences. *Anything* you try will take a long time because the server has to scan the entire table to parse the data before it can start using them without any indexes. That means another table scan, this time with data stored in tempdb.

Comment: Comma-separated or otherwise delimited values in a column is the original sin of database schema design. This needs to be **fixed** (because it really is _broken_), which probably also means updating the application.

Comment: The "indexed view" you're trying to create is actually the normalized many-to-many table you (the company) should have created from the start. It won't help unless you join with it, not the source table. Why not create that many-to-many table? You'll only have to run the slow query once. After that, if people insist on using the denormalized IDs you can create a trigger that splits new values and updates the many-to-may table.

Comment: You're only using compatability mode in that specific database. copy the data to tempdb, use split_string etc to fix your data then insert it into the target database.

Comment: Cant remember if 2008 supports CLR functions, but you can wrote your own function in C# and import it to SQL (if supported) and do the parsing there.  That is until you get the design fixed, this will haunt you at every turn till you fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Don't even get me started on some of the design decisions in this application. It is 10 years old and I really wish I could tear it up and start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thom A for pointing me to this in his comment. The solution I've used is

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ExplodedProductIds
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
WITH tmp (ProductId, DataItem, String)
AS (
   SELECT ProductId,
          CAST(LEFT(OtherProductIds, CHARINDEX(',', IC.AdditionalProductTestIds + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS DataItem,
          CAST(STUFF(OtherProductIds, 1, CHARINDEX(',', IC.OtherProductIds + ','), '') AS VARCHAR(100)) AS String
   FROM ProductSalesTable IC
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ProductId,
          CAST(LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(100)),
          CAST(STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '') ASVARCHAR(100))
   FROM tmp
   WHERE String > '')
SELECT DISTINCT
       ProductId,
       DataItem
FROM tmp
WHERE ProductId IS NOT NULL
      AND DataItem IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

The query has dropped to around 5 seconds using this. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simulate relationship via SQL Server XQuery capabilities.

The proposed solution is using a so called *Quantified Expression*.

For the reference: [Quantified Expressions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/quantified-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver16)

Please test it in your environment to check if the performance is acceptable.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, productID_List VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (id, productID_List) VALUES
(123, '123,234,456'),
(456, '987,876,512'),
(777, '987,999,512');

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, description VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl2 (id, description) VALUES
(234, 'Car'),
(999, 'Bike');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(productID_List, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
INNER JOIN @tbl2 AS t2 ON c.value('some $r in /root/r/text()
          satisfies sql:column("t2.id") =  $r', 'BIT') = 1;
```

**Output**

| id | productID_List | id | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123,234,456 | 234 | Car |
| 777 | 987,999,512 | 999 | Bike |

Comment: It's a good idea but the data is being added to regularly. I was hoping the indexed view would refresh only after another batch of entries and takes away the overhead of separating the comma separated list out which is what appears to be taking the longest time. Using apply means I can't use it to make the indexed view.